# How to create an interactive wall?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, interactive, cinder

I am a graphics/web designer with basic JS/php coding knowledge and I am interested in learning to make interactive walls.

I would like to know from anyone experienced at this. 
What tools, languages do you use?

Unity, Flash, Cinder....etc. which makes it easier?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by interactive wall? Will it talk to me? :P, just kidding. What kind of interaction do you want from the wall?

Comment: lol..and if it could make coffee...it'll be great...i'm talking about stuff like this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5hJujdW8nw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want basic interaction, po-motion.com is a really easy place to start. It tracks motion for simple effects like leaves being brushed away or revealing one image under another. It works using blog detection and can be set up with a mac or pc using a USB camera and any display you can connect your computer to. It also supports some versions of the Kinect on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite hard to make with "basic knowledge of JS/php". However how I think you would handle this would be to make the application as you would normally, but have it be controlled by touch input. And then your wall would be a touch/pressure controlled. Im not an engineer, just a programmer, so I dont know how you would make the actual wall, but I do know unity has some good syntax for touch input which I have used. This is very broad question, but I would recommend looking into unity's pre-built touch classes and input interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

as you have alluded to in your tags, one solution is to create a gesture-controlled solution with Kinect.
The best starting point for this would be to download the SDK and get the hardware:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/

The SDK comes with demos and existing working C# code in Kinect Explorer that creates the 'interactive wall' experience (see Controls Basics, documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188701.aspx).

You can practically run the demo and replace the images to get your experience started. Just make sure you have the right specs on your machine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx ), and you have a good screen.

In terms of programming language, there's no better opportunity to learn C# than from these demos :p